# Como puedo copiar los datos de una matriz bidimensional a otra vacía

Tags: c#

Tengo un método en una clase que me retorna una matriz bidimensional, hasta aquí perfecto, pero necesito en mi clase principal pasar su contenido a otra vacía. ¿Cómo hago para copiarla sin tener que recorrer todos sus elementos? Aclaro que esta matriz es declarada como Object ya que sus elementos son de diferentes tipos de datos.

Código donde lleno la matriz

```
public Object[,] Consultas(String tabla,String columnas,String where)
    {
        String[] nombreColumna = columnas.Split(',');
        int totalFilas = totFilas(tabla);
        Object[,] data = new object[totalFilas,nombreColumna.Length];
        Console.WriteLine("Filas= "+data.GetLength(0));
        Console.WriteLine("Columnas= "+data.GetLength(1));
        Console.WriteLine();
        String consulta = "SELECT " + columnas + " FROM " + tabla;
        if (where != null)
        {
            consulta += " WHERE " + where;
        }
        comandoConsulta.Parameters.Clear();
        comandoConsulta.CommandText = consulta;
        SQLiteDataReader lector = comandoConsulta.ExecuteReader();
        if (lector.HasRows)
        {
            int fila = 0;
            while (lector.Read())
            {
                for (int columna = 0; columna < nombreColumna.Length; columna++)
                {
                     //compruebo que si lee y lo hace
                    //Console.Write(lector.GetValue(columna)+" ");  
                    data[fila, columna] = lector.GetValue(columna);
                    //compruebo que carga datos a la matriz y lo hace
                    Console.Write(data[fila,columna]+" ");
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            fila++;
        }
        
        Console.WriteLine("---------------Fin medoto-------------------------");
        //Cerrar el DataReader
        lector.Close();
        return data;
    }
```

Código de la clase principal donde necesito copiarla, es aquí donde me esta dejando loco, ya que el método `.copyTo()` me da a entender que copia matrices unidimensionales

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Conexion conexion = new Conexion("bolas.db");
        Console.WriteLine(conexion.DimeConexion.FileName);
        Operaciones oper = new Operaciones(conexion.DimeConexion);
        Object[,] data=null;
        data=oper.Consultas("sorteos", "numSorteo,fecha,num1,num2,num3,num4,num5,sol1,sol2", null);
        
        for (int fila = 0; fila < data.GetLength(0); fila++)
        {
            for (int columna = 0; columna <data.GetLength(1); columna++)
            {
                Console.Write(data[fila,columna]+" ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
```

Comment: a donde la estas copiando?

Comment: lo que quiero es copiar el valor devuelto del método .Consultas(parametros entrada) en otra tabla bidimensional sin tener que recorrelas en bucles,

Comment: o que quiero es copiar el valor devuelto del método .Consultas(parametros entrada) en otra tabla bidimensional sin tener que recorrelas en bucles, supongamos que tengo Data (tabla de dos dimensiones llena de datos), Data2(tabla de dos dimensiones vácia), Esto es posible? Data2=data; o tengo que recorrer las tablas para pasar los datos de una a otra ?

Comment: vos queres copiar o queres quedarte con la referencia? porque queres "copiar" y no te alcanza con la devuelta? queres tener 2 veces la matriz?

Comment: Data2=data esto es copiar la referencia de una matriz en otra matriz.. no hay problema.. pero... sigo sin enteder porque queres "copiar", salvo que quieras una copia...

Comment: Exacto, quiero copiar el contenido y no la referencia, ya que lo que me devuelve mi método es una matriz, al copiarla trabajaría con la copia (es mas que nada para realizar pruebas),simplemente es para imprimir el resultado por consola, lo que intento hacer es una clase que me incluya las operaciones básicas de manejo de SqLite, como consultas, añadir, modificar y eliminar

Comment: Sigo sin entender porque queres copiarla.. lo que te devuelve, es una nueva.. para que queres copiarla a otra? Salvo que tengas datos y quieras mover solo algunos, no entiendo el sentido de lo que queres hacer con las matrices...

Comment: bueno, olvidemos el copiar las tablas, ahora viene la pregunta del millón, como puedo representar esta tabla en un datagrid (uso WPF), que pasos debo seguir, estado navegando, y se habla de dataadapter,datatable,dataset,databindig ,la idea es representar los datos recoguidos de una consulta en un datagrid , muchas gracias por tu tiempo

Comment: Si bueno.. si esa tu pregunta principal, y no tiene nada que ver con esto!... en ese caso te diria, usa un ORM y devolve una lista que se conecta sola a una grilla wpf...

Comment: no conocia la ORM, estado navegando y leyendo sobre el tema, y parece una forma mas sencilla de trabajar con bases de datos, pero antes de llegar a ese punto quiero pasarme por las manos y conocer un poco el lenguaje sql, ten encuenta que soy muy principiante en el mundillo de la programacin orientada a objetos ´y es mas mi oficio es otro esto de la programación lo hago como hoby, yo vengo de la edad de piedra cuando no existia internet,programacion espagueti,asi y todo te agradezco mucho tu ayuda y espero que sigais  aclarando mis dudas cuando las necesite

Comment: ORM no tiene nada que ver con sql.. podes aprender un sql y usar un ORM que no haga magia (como dapper)... una cosa no quita la otra...

Comment: Entonces, volviendo a esta pregunta, lo que te esta devolviendo tu metodo es una nueva matriz.. para que queres copiarlo a otra nueva?